# Change the first header tag in the document (<h2>,<h3>..<h6>) to <h1>

Tags: javascript, jquery

If `<h1>` doesn't exist, find the first header tag in the document (one of either `<h2>` through `<h6>`), and if the tags text equals the title text, change the element to `<h1 class="heading1">`.

This works as far as I can tell, but there has to be a more efficient way to write it.

```
var titleText = $('title').html()
var hOne = $('h1:eq(0)');
var hTwo = $('h2:eq(0)');
var hThree = $('h3:eq(0)');
var hFour = $('h4:eq(0)');
if (hOne.html() == titleText)
{
    return;
}
else if (hTwo.html() == titleText)
{
    var hTwoText = hTwo.html();
    hTwo.replaceWith(function () {
        return '<h1 class="heading1">' + hTwoText + "</h1>";
    });
}
else if (hThree.html() == titleText)
{
    var hThreeText = hThree.html();
    hThree.replaceWith(function () {
        return '<h1 class="heading1">' + hThreeText + "</h1>";
    });
}

else if (hFour.html() == titleText)
{
    var hFourText = hFour.html();
    hFour.replaceWith(function () {
        return '<h1 class="heading1">' + hFourText + "</h1>";
    });
}
```

Comment: Your first if has else in front of it...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If you are trying to fix your HTML for structural/SEO reasons, it won't work as most crawlers don't run your JavaScript.

Comment: This is not for SEO reasons. I removed the first "else" (oversite from when I tried adding in an "if h1 = titleText")

Comment: `if (hTwo.text = titleText)` isn't testing logic you need to use `==` or `===`

Comment: _This works as far as I can tell_ I don't think so, DOM elements have no `text` property and `if (hTwo.text = titleText)` is always true.

Comment: Does your page has really multiple titles? var titleText = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].text

Comment: @undefined He's actually accessing the property off jQuery collections, not that those have `text` properties either

Comment: Something dies a little in me every time I see plain JavaScript and jQuery mixed in such way...

Comment: @Asad: undefined refered to the first line, which has no jQuery collection.

Comment: Why are you adding classes to the h elements? You can just target them with the element tag, they are already semantic.

Comment: fyi, the solution i put up earlier, i just confirmed working under all your given criteria. give it a try!

Comment: Thank you for the variety of suggestions. I know that many of the solutions work wonderfully. The one I chose happened to be easiest to manipulate for implementing in my actual source in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/odomoz/1/edit)

```js
$(function () {
  var title,
      headerToReplace,
      replacer;

  if ( $('h1').length === 0 ) {
    title = document.title;
    headerToReplace = $(':header').filter(function () {
      return $(this).text() === title;
    });

    if (headerToReplace.length) {
      replacer = $('<h1 />', { 'class': 'heading1', text: 'title' });
      headerToReplace.first().replaceWith(replacer);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Removed quotations marks from text: 'title'
Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> ***CONFIRMED WORKING***

I don't have a great example as this took many back and forth's on jsFiddle to confirm, but i have test this against multiple h-Tag's, existing h1's, non-existing h1's and every other variation i could think of for your question. The following 1 simple line of jQuery will do the job every time, unless there is more than one "title" tag, in which case just add .first or .last to the title call in the filter.

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').filter(function(i) { return $(this).text() == $("title").text() }).first().each(function(i) { $(this).replaceWith($('<h1>' + $(this).html() + '</h1>')); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
function getHeader() {
    var headers = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'];

    for (var i = 0, z = headers.length; i < z; i++)
    if ($(headers[i]).length) {
        return '<h1 class="heading1">' + $(headers[i]).text() + "</h1>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
var hElem, content;

for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    //Get the element
    hElem = $("h" + i + ":eq(0)");

    //Make sure at least one element exists
    if ( ! hElem.length)
        continue;

    //If h1 exists, stop here
    if (i == 1)
        break;

    //Get the element's inner text
    content = hElem.text();

    //Replace the element if needed and then stop
    if (content == titleText)
    {
        hElem.replaceWith("<h1 class='heading1'>" + content + "</h1>");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed the .text() to .html() and it seems to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $firstHeader = ​$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').first();​​​​​​​​

if (​​​​​​$firstHeader​[0].tagName !== 'H1' && &firstHeader.text() === $('title').text()) {
    ​​​var headerContent = $firstHeader.html();
    $firstHeader.replaceWith($('<h1 class="heading1"></h1>').html(headerContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not useful if

- `h2-h6` elements might contain the title as a substring of them
- title contains a double quote in it

If you want an exact match, then you would look further into this.

```
var titleText = $('title').text();
if (!$('h1:eq(0)').length) {
    var selectors = [], i = 2;
    for (i; i < 7; i++) { 
        selectors.push('h'+i+':contains("'+titleText+'"):eq(0)');
    }
    var $el = $(selectors.join(',')).first();
    $el.replaceWith('<h1 class="heading1">'+$el.text()+'</h1>');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/7VbRB/)